# Auto-generate class hierarchy and code structure in Eclipse

Tags: java

How can I auto-generate class hierarchy diagrams and documentation from function/class headers in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javadoc for generating the documentation of function/class headers. 
Javadoc processes only comments of the form:

/**
* Here your function (or class) comments

* @version 2.5     # TAGS

* @author John Doe

* ...

*/

You can use a set of predefined tags such as @version, @author, @param among many others. 
For complete documentation of the javadoc tool check here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html

If you want to generate the documentation using javadoc from Eclipse follow these steps:

1) Open your project

2) File->Export

3) Select Javadoc from the Java folder

4) Follow the other instructions. The documentation will be generated in the path you entered